# How to use PIE with Compass on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, compass-sass, css3pie

I can`t understand after reading documentation and looking through similar issues, how to use PIE with compass on rails.

```
@import compass/css3/pie
```

and what next or before it? Am i to install pie? Ok i have run `@ compass install compass/pie` it doesn`t seem to be the end.

Could you please provide a step by step instruction how to add a simple mixing to an element to get it work in IE? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you including the PIE.htc file for IE browsers and delivering it with the mime-type text/x-component?

Comment: Please explain where should i add the .htc file, can i use htc.js? Could you please provide a mini-instruction?

Comment: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/pie/

Comment: This documentation is not really helpful... There is no CSS generated for CSS PIE.